# Validation error message persists after refreshing(f5) the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have index page of Student with 5 dropdown list if the selected elements are wrong or business validation fails i written redirect to index page with error message but after getting index page with error message if i entered f5(refresh) error message will not gone instead its persist please help me to get know this.
thanx.

Comment: make sure your error message display property is set to dynamic

Comment: Without code how we can know that what is wrong in your code.